# Can't install python modules on ansible master

Tags: ansible, python-module

I've installed ansible on a centos 7 VM using yum. I'm currently running version 2.3.0.

I've tried to use the "digital_ocean" module using hosts: "localhost", but I've got the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "dopy >= 0.3.2 required for this module"}
```

I figured I needed to install a python module. Unfortunately, apparently python was not installed on my host because pip program was not found.

I installed pip using yum:

```
yum install -y python-pip
```

And then I installed the dopy module:

```
sudo pip install 'dopy>=0.2.3,<=0.2.3'
```

But unfortunately, even after that I still have the same error. I guess the installed python package is not picked up by ansible, maybe because ansible must have it's own python package repo in the machine (not familiar with python).

What should I do ?

Comment: Install the requested version of `dopy`.

Comment: Thanks silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Of course I misread the versions and thought I was installing the correct one.
I tried to install dopy version 3.2.0, but it didn't existed.
I installed last version instead and it worked.